# Cocoa WebView - Loading a local HTML page

Tags: cocoa, webview

After browsing quite a bit, I still can't figure this out. I've added a HTML page and its images directory into my project Resources group in Xcode (Copied them over).

When I try to load the WebView with the following code, the text is displayed fine, but the images aren't loaded.

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[[tempWebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:url];
```

EDIT: Sorry about the delay, here's some basic html that failed.

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <img src="images/bg.png"></img> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And my edited code looks like this -

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[[webView1 mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

EDIT2: Just realized it was an issue with the path. Apparently `<img src = "images/bg.png">` doesn't work, but if I copy bg.png to the root directory and say `<img src = "bg.png">` everything works fine. I'm still not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: Show us some sample HTML referencing an image.

Answer (score 8):

Consider doing the following:

1. Instead of getting the resource path and stapling a subpath onto it yourself, [ask the bundle to give you the correct path](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:).
2. Instead of handling a path at all, [ask the bundle to give you the correct URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:). (Requires Mac OS X 10.6 or later.)
3. Instead of injecting HTML contents directly into the frame, [ask the WebView to load the URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setMainFrameURL:).

This reduces your code to two lines that, if the HTML code is correct, will work.

Comment: Actually, my initial implementation was like that. But, I saw one of the SO questions where someone was having the same problem, but fixed it by implementing it this way. I was wondering if it has something to do with the baseURL maybe.

Comment: Tejaswi Yerukalapudi: Got a link to one of those questions?

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find it now, but I've edited my implementation to follow this. It appears that my issue is with using syntax that navigates to a sub-folders to grab the images in HTML. I kinda _get_ why this is happening, but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it, thanks for all your help again!

Comment: Tejaswi Yerukalapudi: So if you look in the app bundle in your build folder, were you able to find the images directory copied there? (Also, there aren't supposed to be spaces around the equal sign in HTML.)

Comment: Oops, that was me just typing into SO directly, the original HTML doesn't have them. And, yes, the images were copied over.

Comment: Tejaswi Yerukalapudi: Not what I asked. Did you find the images *directory* copied there?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see this comment. Yes, the images directory was copied over too. Right now, we were making it for a demo, so I could host the page on the local apache instance in that mac and access it using http://localhost/xyz.html, I think I need to find a permanent fix for it though, please let me know if I'm doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the problem here is to do with how files are copied to the resources directory during the build phase. Any folders that are shown as groups in Xcode will be flattened when they are copied across. If you are adding an entire website folder structure to your project you must select "Create folder references for any added folders" when adding the structure.

An example:
I have an html file that references an image in a folder of the same name. I add all this into my project selecting 'folder references':

[image: Adding the files]

The files will look like this in my project (note the blue folder):

[image: Project tree]

When the project is built the web contents folder will be maintained:

[image: Resources folder in the bundle]

There is no need to start setting base URLs or loading with strings.
The web page can now be successfully loaded like this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LocalTestWeb" withExtension:@"html"];
[[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me (only having issues with Canvas):

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                     ofType:@"html"
                                                inDirectory:@"html_files_folder"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the image file data in base64 string. And put that string in img tag as below.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

See this for more details: http://danielmclaren.com/node/90