# Can you add an html file in the xcode groups folder and open it in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html

I want to load an html file on a web view without having to upload it to the web. I have the file in my groups folder in xcode. Can i open this in a webview?

Comment: looks like a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885641/cocoa-webview-loding-a-local-html-page

Comment: didn't work :( Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Just get the path to your resource, and tell your webview to load it. This should be similar to what you'd need.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyHTMLPage" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Where the webView is an IBOutlet to your UIWebView