# Local html or pdf file in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to open a local (not on the web) html file or a pdf file in Cocoa, but not in iOS.  I can find lots examples that use UIKit, but haven't found a complete set of code ideas that use WebKit.  Can someone please help by pointing me in the right direction or offering some ideas on how todo this.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885641/cocoa-webview-loding-a-local-html-page

Comment: Thank you.  That was helpful and it moved the project forward.  Using a set up for a pdf file it looks like it is unable to find the file. I'll ask about that in another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the suggestions on this question. 
Following is the code that I used

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"myDocumentText"
                          ofType:@"pdf"]; 
    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];   

}
```