# Cocoa WebView (MacApp) - how to use custom fonts?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, fonts, webkit

I have a WebView in a Cocoa application (macgap).

(*NOTE I'm not talking about a UIWebView in an iOS app*)

In my CSS file, there are some custom font declarations:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Quivira';
    src:url("./Quivira.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

I can't get these to load however - some sort of security issue I believe.

Sometimes, I can see there is an error in the console "**Not allowed to load local resource: Quivira.ttf**" (it doesn't always show this though)

What could be causing this? The index.html file is loaded via the file:/// protocol so there shouldn't be a security issue, as it is already local and should therefor be able to load local resources.

I'm thinking it could be a bug in webkit.

Is anyone able to load custom fonts in a Cocoa WebView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried two approaches to load webpages with custom fonts.

- From the app bundle (using NSBundle)
- From a local path specified by the user (using absolute path)

In both cases I am successfully able to display Custom Fonts. There is a HTML file and beside it, a .ttf font file. In the HTML file I have defined @font-face in inline CSS.

In the second case you can give any full path from local filesystem and the webview will load from that (like /Users/johndoe/Desktop/maiwebsite/index.html).

**[Code is on Github](https://github.com/n9986/WebViewCustomFonts).**

And from [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885641/cocoa-webview-loding-a-local-html-page):

1. Instead of getting the resource path and stapling a subpath onto it yourself, [ask the bundle to give you the correct path](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:).
2. Instead of handling a path at all, [ask the bundle to give you the correct URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:). (Requires Mac OS X 10.6 or later.)

If this doesn't help then could you put up your code somewhere so we can try to debug it?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort you went to! OK, well it must be a bug in macgap - something in there must be causing the index.html file to not be considered a local file.  I have an example here: https://github.com/asgeo1/macgap/tree/test_quivera If you compile that branch, you will see that the Quivera font never loads in the WebView. You can tell this, because the Quivera font is needed to display the unicode 'double flat' symbol () in a WebView. My app needs to be able to display that unicode symbol.

Comment: Let me take a step back. I can see that with your example, the double-flat symbol works regardless of whether I use Quivira or not - which is great. (In iOS, the only way to get the double-flat symbol to work in a UIWebView is to use Quivira, so I must have made that assumption that a WebView in OS X had the same issue. It doesn't - awesome)

Comment: But I still have a problem, when using MacGap for some reason it's not showing the double-flat symbol. I originally thought that was because I couldn't get it to load Quivira, but your example proves that the font used shouldn't be the issue. I just don't see what is the difference in how the UIWebView works from your example vs the macgap example I posted above. It's weird.

Comment: OK, I can see I forgot to use <meta charset="utf-8"> in my above example, so that's why the double-flat is not working. That's not the issue my actual app has though - it's something else. Anyway... this now has nothing to do with the original question. I should really work out what the underlying problem is and post another question if necessary. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped in some way. And I guess I'll fork macgap. It is rather interesting. I think I'll fork and contribute some time soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

For WKWebView (WebView now deprecated), load custom fonts from the MacApp bundle like so:

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Unlike iOS where all one needs to supply for bundle resources is: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` (iOS Bundle is flatter), for MacApps the path to resources is more complex and bundlePath alone will NOT work. The above approach DOES work.

In your CSS simply use `@font-face` like so and any fonts in the location specified by `resourceURL` will be found.

```
@font-face {font-family:'myfont';src:url('myfont.ttf');}
```