# xcode cocoa Button that opens html file in new window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am a bit stuck,...

I have my app written, and I now only need to have a button that opens an HTML document that is in the resource folder of my app.

So if you click the button the html file will open in a new window or in safari. Whatever that is the easiest way to do this.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885641/cocoa-webview-loding-a-local-html-page

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your file from the path.

If it is in resource folder (i.e. NSBundle) then ok, else Get the path.

Read the html and show it.

You can do it is two ways, second way is using NSAppleScript, which is not good for sandboxed application.

And first way is showing it in webView.

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                               ofType:@"html"/*or htm as per your file extension*/
                                          inDirectory:@"yourDirectoryName"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your file name" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview setDelegate:self];
webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```